# double && check inside unslider.js plugin , what is it doing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i am having a problem understanding the line of code inside the below function :

```
function lala (index, callback){

         $.isFunction(o.starting) && !callback && o.starting(el, li.eq(current));

    }
```

consider the below ,

$.isfunction is checking of (o.starting) is a function ,

now suppose i am calling function lala as follows :

lala(1); // i am passing a parameter only for index , nothing for callback does that mean that if inside function 
            lala i have a check `!callback` , this will return true ??

also whats is this line really doing :

```
$.isFunction(o.starting) && !callback && o.starting(el, li.eq(current));
```

i have seen things like :

```
(o.autoload) && dothis();
```

the above line reads , if o.autoload is true go ahead and execute dothis();

but what does the below line mean ? its pritty scary to be honest ?

```
$.isFunction(o.starting) && !callback && o.starting(el, li.eq(current));
```

is it checking for two conditions I.e.

```
$.isFunction(o.starting) && !callback
```

and than executing :

```
o.starting(el, li.eq(current));
```

**EDIT ::**

On doing a bit of reading i just want to confirm something :

Example One :

```
function lala(index, callback) {
  if($.isFunction(o.starting) && !callback) o.starting(el, li.eq(current));
}
```

the above if statement inside the fnction reads as "if both conditions are true" execute `o.starting(el, li.eq(current));`.

so is the above example different from :

Example 2 :

```
$.isFunction(o.starting) && !callback && o.starting(el, li.eq(current));
```

i guess on the above lines no function is being executed . just true or false values being returned . AM I RIGHT ?? and if false was returned for any of the 3 statements the lines of code that come after that line would not execute . AM I COMPLETELY right in MY ASSUMPTION ??

Comment: It's a logical AND, if starts at the beginning, and as long as `isFunction` is truthy, it continues to the next one, and if `!callback` is thruthy it continues to the next one, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks , i usually see logical operators like this if(lala && bla bla){
 do_this();
} .. but in the real world , things just seems , much more complicated . Thanks though .

Comment: It's seems like just a clever way to execute the functions based on wether or not the previous checks are truthy etc.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks Evil Genious ! just out of curiousity are u Bjarne Stroustrup ?

Comment: You're welcome, and no I'm not Bjarne, in fact I'm not very good at C++ at all, but I have been meaning to learn. Bjarne is a member though -> http://stackoverflow.com/users/109934/bjarne-stroustrup

Comment: No wonder his one answer fetched him almost 200 upvotes LOL . anyways , TY and c u around .

Comment: @adeneo just added a edit ! incase ur free just comment back and tell me if what i assumed is right or wrong ! . Thanks

Comment: The functions are being executed, at least the first one, and if that returns a truthy value, it continues to the second one, which isn't a function, just a variable, and it negates it so if it's falsy, it continues to the last function. The clever thing about this is that if the first function is falsy, there's no need to check the other two, and it doesn't, it only continues to the next step if the value is truthy, so both the two first values has to be truthy for the third function to execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70342/discussion-between-alexander-solonik-and-adeneo).